# How to select unicode whitespace characters from oracle?

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm trying to find clobs in an oracle database that contain specific unicode whitespace characters, but I'm not sure how to the select statement can be written.

Trying the following query, but not sure if this is the correct way to go about it:

```
select * from mytable where my_clob like '%'|| n'0xEF' || '%';
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you know the character code of the character you're looking for, you can use `CHR()` to build an expression to look for the specific code;

```
SELECT * 
FROM mytable 
WHERE my_clob LIKE '%' || CHR(15052183) || '%';
```

[An SQLfiddle to test with](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/88c86/2).

Answer (score 5):

I'm not sure what character you're wanting to search for, but I think it's the `UNISTR` command you're looking for. Also, `LIKE` will do an implicit conversion to `VARCHAR2` (I think), so you're only searching in the first 4000 characters. Try this to search for the non-breaking space:

```
SELECT * 
  FROM mytable
 WHERE dbms_lob.instr( my_clob, UNISTR( '\00A0' )) > 0;
```

https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/functions224.htm#SQLRF06154